# Prove that different definitions of big-Oh with n>=1 or n>N are equivalent

Tags: algorithm, big-o, proof

I am coming across two slightly different definitions of big-oh and need to prove that they are equivalent to each other:

**Definition 1:** 
f(n) = O(g(n)) if there exists constants c and N such that f(n) ≤ c g(n) for all n > N.

**Definition 2:**
f(n) = O(g(n)) if there exists a constant c such f(n) ≤ c g(n) for all n≥1.

Intuitively I know that if we choose c large enough we can get rid of N like in definition 2.
But how to prove that if definition 1 implies definition 2, and vice versa.

Comment: Might be better suited for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @juvian When advising people to post to some other SE site, please also ask them to delete the original question. Having the same question on two different sites fragments answers and wastes peopel's time when they answer a question that already has answers on another site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby will do next time ^^

Comment: @juvian Awesome -- thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They aren't actually equivalent, and (1) is the correct definition.

An example of the difference is that under (1), `n = O(n log(n))` but under definition (2) it can't be because at `n=1` because for any `c`, `c g(n) = c*1*log(1) = 0 < 1`.

The reason why (1) is the correct definition is because the purpose of big-O is to capture behavior "near infinity", and so a finite number of special cases for small `n` should be ignored.

The reason why you'll see (2) show up is because it is sufficient to establish big-O.  It just isn't necessary.

Comment: OK. But let's also mention that the equivalence holds if `g(n)>0` for all values of `n`. In fact, it would be enough to chose `c'=max(f(1)/g(1), ..., f(N)/g(N), c)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain better my comment to @btilly's answer.

When `g(n)>0` for all values of `n`, both definitions are in fact equivalent. Here is why:

Firstly, it is always true that when Definition 2 holds, Definition 1 also holds. In fact, we can choose `N=0` in this case.

Assume now that Definition 1 is satisfied for some constant `c` and some number `N`. If `N=0`, we have Definition 2. If `N>0`, consider the following quantity:

```
c1 := max{f(1)/g(1), ..., f(N)/g(N)}
```

the quotients make sense because we are in the case where `g(n)` is always positive. Besides, since

```
f(n)/g(n) <= c1        (1<=n<=N)
```

we get

```
f(n) <= c1*g(n)        (1<=n<=N)
```

and since `f(n) <= c*g(n)` for `n>N`, it happens that

```
f(n) <= max(c1,c)*g(n)     for all n
```

as Definition 2 requires.